# Why is argparse capitalizing options?

Tags: python, argparse

In the following:

```
$ python df.py -h
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v VERBOSE, --verbose VERBOSE
                        Print debug info on script run.
```

Why does python capitalize the `VERBOSE` arg and why does it print it twice? How can I get it to show like the help line, where it has `-h` for the short option and `--help` for the long option? I am initializing it as follows:

```
my_parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',     required=False, help='Print debug info on script run.')
```

Comment: Try `action='store_true'`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi thanks, can you link to the place in the docs where it shows that?

Comment: it shows two times because this shows that it needs agument and you should run it `df.py --verbose some_value`. If you want only to keep `True/False` then you should use option `action='store_true'`

Comment: see [action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) in `argparse` doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capital `VERBOSE` represents where the user is supposed to provide a value for the option, because you've declared this option as one that takes a value.

You probably didn't want this option to take a value. You probably wanted `action='store_true'`, which would store `True` if the option is provided and `False` otherwise.